# Enter new data in db (EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have method in controller

It receive  data from post request and write to table

Here is code

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(TimeTable))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(TimeTable timeTable)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
            TimeTable c = (from x in db.TimeTables
                where x.Company == timeTable.Company && x.INN == timeTable.INN
                select x).First();
            c.StartPause = timeTable.StartPause;
            c.StartDay = timeTable.StartDay;
            c.EndPause = timeTable.EndPause;
            c.EndDay = timeTable.EndDay;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        db.TimeTables.Add(timeTable);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = timeTable.Id }, timeTable);
    }
```

But it works well when record with INN and Company already in db.

But if it not in database I need to create new entry.

How I need to modify  this method?

Comment: The subject says `LINQ to SQL` but that looks very like Entity Framework: please confirm which ORM you are using (and tag the question correctly). Thanks

Comment: Edit my question@Richard

Comment: I edited my answer please see this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag (`exisingCompanyFlag`) for edit mode or add new mode like this

```
    bool existingCompanyFlag = true;
    TimeTable c = (from x in db.TimeTables
                   where x.Company == timeTable.Company && x.INN == timeTable.INN
                         select x).FirstOrDefult();

    if (c == null)
    {
      existingCompanyFlag = false;
      c = new TimeTable();
    }   
    c.StartPause = timeTable.StartPause;
    c.StartDay = timeTable.StartDay;
    c.EndPause = timeTable.EndPause;
    c.EndDay = timeTable.EndDay;
    if (!existingCompanyFlag)
       db.TimeTables.Add(c);
```

Comment: In the case the instance isn't found you'll need to create an instance (`FirstOrDefault` will return null if not found).

Comment: It creates new row on every request. I need to create it only if `x.Company  && x.INN` is null

Comment: All okay. It was my fault

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate branch in your code for the insert case.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
  if (addingNewRow) {
    TimeTable tt = new TimeTable {
     // Populate properties (except identity columns)
    };
    db.TimeTables.Add(tt);
  } else {
    // update
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

To link to other entities use one of:

1. Assign instances:

   ```
   x.Company = theCompany;
   ```
2. or, assign the instance id

   x.CompanyId = companyId;

(#1 is easier if you already have the other entity loaded or are creating it – EF will sort out the ids – while #2 saves loading the whole other entity.)